# задача с собеседования

Tags: задание-на-собеседовании

> На столе перед Вами лежат белые пластиковые карточки 73 шт. На всех карточках невидимыми чернилами написаны порядковые номера. Без спец средств невозможно определить, какой стороной вверх лежит карточка (номером вверх или пустой стороной). Известно, что номером вверх рандомно лежат 7 карточек (остальные 66 номером вниз). Каким образом разделить эти карточки на 2 группы, чтобы в каждой из групп было одинаковое количество карточек с номером вверх (карточки можно переворачивать неограниченное кол-во раз)?

Comment: Это собеседование на должность фокусника или шпиона?

Comment: https://masterok.livejournal.com/3628166.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полчаса убил, оказалось проще простого.
Отсчитываем x - количество номером вверх карточек ( в нашем случае 7 ) и переворачиваем их.
Математически выглядит так:
X - количество карточек лицом вверх.
из кучи вытащили X карточек, после чего у нас образовалось 2 кучки, среди которых карточки лицом вверх распределились случайно.
Пусть в первой кучке их будет N, тогда здесь же будет X - N карточек лицом вниз, так как всего X карточек лицом вверх, а N из них уже в первой кучке. следовательно во второй кучке их останется X - N.
Остается перевернуть первую кучку тогда и в первой и во второй будет ровно по X - N карточек, лежащих лицом вверх.